# How can I solve this question according to TSQL syntax?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I was studying for a test until this question appeared

These are the tables (primary keys are in bold):

- `Employee` (**id**, name, emailAddress),
- `Email` (**emailId**, senderId, receiverId, subject)
- `EmailDetails` (**emailId**, date, status)

The question states that:

- Two employees are connected if they sent an email to each other

  - (i.e. each employee should have at least sent the other one or more emails).
- Find all pairs of employees who are connected.

  - (return their ID).

Can someone please help me solving this out?

Comment: Why is `EmailDetails` denormalized? (i.e. `EmailDetails`' can be moved into the `Email` table - why is it a separate table instead?)

Comment: T-SQL is specific to MS SQL Server and Sybase, but you've added tags for MySQL and Access - please remove all tags except for the RDBMS you're actually using - which you haven't specified. Also, please confirm that `Email.senderId` and `Email.reciverId` are FKs to `Employee`.

Comment: Your question says to return "all pairs" of `Employee.id` values for connected employees, but is being "connected" a transitive and/or reciprocal? Or is it unidirectional?

Comment: Regarding why EmailDetails is a seperate table, I totally agree with you but this is how the tables are stated in the question, and regarding FKs yes receiverID and senderID are both foreign keys to the Employee table on ID. Finally for the "connected" issue they didn't state whether it should be transitive or unidirectional, but I think they meant unidirectional since we didn't cover transitive and reciprocal cases in this course. Thanks for your help. @Dai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check only the email table, if an id is sender and receiver

```
SELECT DISTINCT senderID,receiverID  FROM Email e 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM Email  
              WHERE receiverID = e.senderID AND senderIF = e.receiverID))
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to correctly answer this question you need to mark which columns in the given tables serve as foreign keys, i.e. their values correspond to each other. Are senderid and receiverid id in the employees table? if so:

```
SELECT 
    emp1.id AS sender, 
    emp2.id AS receiver 
FROM employee emp1
JOIN email e ON emp1.id = e.senderid
JOIN employee emp2 ON emp2.id = e.receiverid
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all pairs, so (bob, kate) and (kate, bob).

```
select distinct e1.senderID, e1.receiverID
from email e1 join email e2
on e1.receiverID = e2.senderID and e2.receiverID = e1.senderID;
```

To get only one of those add at the end a condition:

```
where e1.senderId > e1.receiverID
```